# How to fetch an image in alt tag coming from a link

Tags: reactjs

I am working with img tags such that if src unable to fetch the image then alt will show an image which is coming from a link.Basically i want my alt to fetch image from an URL.

1.I tried simply pasting that link ahead of alt

```
alt="www.some/random/link.jpg"
```

2. assigned a variable

```
render(){
    var link = "www.some/random/link.jpg"
    return(
        <div>
            <img src="some_image_source" alt={link}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am getting the actual link as plain text instead i need an image.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML img  attibute**:

> The required alt attribute specifies an alternate **text** for an image if the image cannot be displayed.

So `alt` takes **text** and display if the image can not be loaded for some reason. **`alt` is not the alternative image for `src`**.

Maybe you can make a component for this, when the `src` of  is not loaded, change the `src` to something can be load.

Answer (score 0):

I have added onError and which calls a function whenever main photo faces an error.

```
 <img src={main photo} onError={this.addDefaultSrc}    

addDefaultSrc(e) {
e.target.src = 'alternate photo'
  }
```